# Nuxt.js: Use middlware from a specific route to its all child routes

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-router

I have a route for `/admin/users` that acts as a parent route for all of its child routes. (e.g. `/admin/users/@username/stats` or `/admin/users/@username/logs` etc.).
There will be many nested routes as well, so how do I use specific middleware to all of `/admin/users`'s child routes?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [dynamic route](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/features/file-system-routing#dynamic-routes) for `/admin/users/_username/_param.vue`, and use the [`middleware` prop](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/components-glossary/pages-middleware) in the `_param.vue` page:

```js
// /pages/admin/users/_username/_param.vue
export default {
  middleware({ params, redirect }) {
    console.log('params', params.username, params.param)

    // https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/internals-glossary/context#redirect
    // Redirect to the child route, passing along any route parameters.
    // `params.param` is 'stats' or 'logs'
    redirect({ name: params.param, params })
  }
}
```

Comment: suppose there are more than 10 sub routes for `/admin/users`. Then how do I apply middleware on all child routes of `/admin/users` with least effort?

Comment: @Swapnil The approach I described in my answer would still apply. Do you have a GitHub link to a repo that might clarify your exact scenario?